# Interact with a multi-level object via a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to write a service that maintains a multi-level config object.  I want to be able to set and change the values of these at any point in time.

In usage it would be called like this: `config.setValue(key, data)`. An example might be `config.setValue("myConfigObject.myConfigAttribute", "myString")`

On the other side of the service, there is a variable named `config` that holds a blank object (`{}`) to start, and has values set to it.  There is a `setData` function that can override the blank object with a new object, and this happens early in my application startup to supply some initial values.

The `setValue` function in my service looks like this:

```
configService.setValue = function(key, data){
    // Create a set defer
    var setDefer = $q.defer();

    // If we have data, a key, and a valid config object
    if (data && key && config){

        // Set the value
        var tempObject = $.extend({}, config);
        var object = tempObject;

        // Loop over each of the keys
        for (var i=0, j=keys.length; i<j; i++){
            // If there is a valid object
            if (object[keys[i]]){

                // Move down in the config object
                object = object[keys[i]];
            } else {

                // Otherwise the value is not yet set, and we will set the value at this level
                object[keys[i]] = data;
                config = tempObject;
                setDefer.resolve();
            }
        }

        // Resolve the defer
        object = data;
        config = tempObject;
        setDefer.resolve();
    } else {
        // Reject the defer
        setDefer.reject();
    }

    return setDefer.promise;
};
```

This is about the most verbose I could make it, I tried to several other more succinct ways, but none of them worked.  Well, that's not entirely true.  All of them worked (including this one), but only when a value does not already exist.  If the value already exists, it refuses to overwrite it.  If the value does not exist, it sets it as expected in the correct place.

Can anyone please explain this to me, or is their a better approach I should be taking?

Comment: Why are you using `$q.defer`? None of what you are doing is an async action

Comment: Because regardless of the fact that it is not technically "async" the operation does take time to complete, and if the next line of code after the line that calls this depends on the new data, it needs to only happen after these actions have completed, which means using `.then`, which requires a promise which requires a defer.  This prevents race conditions and using timeouts.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding how code execution works then. Javascript is a single-thread execution environment (for the purposes relevant to this question), and any syncronous code, regardless of how long it takes to execute, will *necessarily* complete before the next line of code executes

Comment: Tell that to the race condition that adding a promise solved.  I understand that's how it SHOULD work, I also understand that's not how it WAS working.

Comment: Then you had some other issue that you misdiagnosed as a race condition. Take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtLm2VjRq583B1d4edZn?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)?

Angular already has to solve this issue with mustache notation, e.g. a ng-model can set a value of an attribute on an object that is undefined. This is done via $parse.

You should be able do something like

```
var getter = $parse(key);
var setter = getter.assign;
var context = rootConfigMap;// have a base object that has different config objects as children.
setter(context, newValue);
```